# The correct COPY command to load postgreSQL data from csv file that has single-quoted data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, copy, quote

I have csv file that has contents like this:

```
10,53073,0,0,'Y','2008-05-30 21:46:55',0,'2008-05-30 21:48:04',0,53071,2
```

I want to load the csv data into my_table.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  ad_tree_id numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
  node_id numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
  ad_client_id numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
  ad_org_id numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
  isactive character(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y'::bpchar,
  created timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  createdby numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
  updated timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updatedby numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
  parent_id numeric(10,0),
  seqno numeric(10,0),
  CONSTRAINT ad_treenodemm_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ad_tree_id , node_id ),
  CONSTRAINT adtree_adtreenodemm FOREIGN KEY (ad_tree_id)
      REFERENCES ad_tree (ad_tree_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
  CONSTRAINT ad_treenodemm_isactive_check CHECK (isactive = ANY (ARRAY['Y'::bpchar, 'N'::bpchar]))
)
```

When I run this command in pgAdmin III tool:

```
COPY my_table FROM 'c:\downloads\file.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```

I got error:

```
ERROR:  value too long for type character(1)
CONTEXT:  COPY my_table, line 1, column isactive: "'Y'"
```

Then I modified the command like this:

```
COPY my_table FROM 'c:\downloads\file.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV QUOTE ''';
COPY my_table FROM 'c:\downloads\file.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV QUOTE '\'';
COPY my_table FROM 'c:\downloads\file.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV QUOTE '\'' ESCAPE '\';
COPY my_table FROM 'c:\downloads\file.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV QUOTE '\'' ESCAPE \;
```

All failed when tried.

So, anyone can show me the correct COPY command for this case?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Double single quotes (if `standard_conforming_strings` is on, see [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS))

```
COPY my_table FROM 'c:\downloads\file.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV QUOTE '''';
```

or use the non-standard PostgreSQL-specific [escape string](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE):

```
COPY my_table FROM 'c:\downloads\file.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV QUOTE E'\'';
```

Comment: If COPY is reserved for the admin users, from psql command line use,  \COPY my_table FROM 'c:\downloads\file.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV QUOTE '''';

Comment: @Tammy `\copy` gets paths relative to the `psql` client, `COPY` gets them relative to the server host.

Answer (score 5):

Some other people who are experiencing this error may want to check the file to see if it contains a header on the first line. While it wasn't the problem in your case, it is worth noting the way to work around it:

```
COPY my_table FROM 'c:\downloads\file.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, I got the answer:

```
COPY my_table FROM 'c:\downloads\file.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV QUOTE '''';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you have column data present with double quotes in .csv files separated by `,`

```
COPY tablename FROM 'c:\downloads\file.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV QUOTE '"';
```